# Dimension of irreducible components of single homogeneous polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm currently working my way through [Algebraic Geometry](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2014/alggeom-2014.pdf) by Andreas Gathmann and could use a hint to exercise 7.9:

Let $ f : \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^m$ be a morphism. Prove:
If $ X \subset \mathbb{P}^m $ is the zero locus of a single homogeneous polynomial in $K[x_0,...,x_m]$ then every irreducible component of $f^{-1}(X)$ has dimension at least $n-1$.

I know that the irreducible components of $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^m$ have dimension $m-1$, but how do i get the needed dimension in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: Use the following theorem (together with Krull's principal ideal theorem) to conclude

> **Theorem:** Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ be an open set and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{P^m}$ a morphism. Then there are unique (except for a constant) homogeneous polynomials $f_0,\dots,f_m\in k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ of the same degree such that $f$ is globally defined by them, i.e, 
>   $$f(x_0:\dots:x_n)=(f_1(x_0:\dots:x_n):\dots:f_m(x_0:\dots:x_n)) \; \; \forall \,(x_0:\dots:x_n)\in U$$

*Hint for the theorem*: First prove the uniqueness, then as there is a cover $U=\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$ such that $f$ is defined by homogeneous polynomials over each $U_i$ (this should be either your definition of morphism or something already proved) by the uniqueness over $U_i\cap U_j$ you can *glue* all this polynomials.

Comment: Hello, thank you for providing a hint. The Theorem you mentioned is already proven in the notes ( lemma 7.5 ). But i still fail to see how i can get the needed proof. I would be thankful if you could extent your hint.

Comment: The idea is that if $X=V(h)$ then $x\in f^{-1}(X) \iff$ $f(x)\in V(h) \iff$ $h(f(x))=0 \iff x\in V(h\circ f)$ So $f^{-1}(X)$ is defined by a single equation and hence is of pure codimension 1. The composition $h\circ f$ is a polynomial because it is the composition of polynomials thanks to the theorem.

Comment: Also, I have just read Lemma 7.5 and is not quite the same. What this lemma tells you is that for a projective variety $X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ you can construct morphisms with domain open subsets of $X$ using homogeneous elements. What the theorem above tells you is that when $X=\mathbb{P}^n$ this are actually *all* the morphisms you can possible construct with domain an open set. This can fail when $X$ is not the entire projective space.